# Is there any uniqueness enforcement of organisation names in trusted SSL certificates?

Tags: security, ssl, https

When applying for SSL certificates there are a number of fields encoded into the certificate including the "Organisation Name". My understanding is that trusted root certificate authorities will conduct a set of investigations to ensure this field is correct before issuing a certificate.

I am looking to use the "Organisation Name" field of my organisation's SSL certificate to ensure I am connecting to one of our servers. In addition I will, of course, also complete the full SSL handshake to ensure the certificate is not stolen or being spoofed. I am using this instead of the server's "Common Name" as this is subject to change.

However, I am concerned the uniqueness of this field cannot be relied upon. **Would it be possible for a different organisation to share the same "Organisation Name" in their trusted SSL certificates?**

**Additionally, if my organisation's name changed legally and another organisation were to adopt our old name, would they be able to register a trusted SSL certificate with the same "Organisation Name"?**

Alternatively if there is a better way to identify my organisation's servers through the SSL certificate I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends completely on the issuing CA. But as far as public certificates go - no, Organisation Name field doesn't have to be unique, or verified in any way. CA/B forum is the place to go to with questions like this. The latest baseline requirement can be found at:

https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/

Regarding the identity it only says:

> The CA SHALL verify the identity and address of the Applicant using documentation provided by, or through communication with, at least one of the following: (methods follow)

There's nothing about uniqueness of the names. Anyone can register a company with a chosen name. If not one country then another one will.

Comment: Thanks. I have now opted to validate the host identity by using the public key of the certificate. This is a much more ratified process called key pinning.